# Updating/removing entries from appSettings

Tags: c#

I am trying to update configuration files from other projects than the one I'm in.
The UpdateConfig() works fine, but the DeleteFromConfig() doesn't remove the entry. 
Let's say I have an entry like this:

add key="someKey" value="oldValue" /

DeleteFromConfig() leaves the entry as before, but if I comment out the Remove line from UpdateConfig and try to change the value to 'newValue'it gives me this:

add key="someKey" value="oldValue,newValue" /

The AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key) line only removes the value, not the entire entry.
Is there a way to remove the whole thing?

```
  private void UpdateConfig(string path, string key, string value)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }

        private void DeleteFromConfig(string path, string key)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }
```

Comment: Because the config file is XML, you could just always edit it using XMLDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the key1 from config using **XmlDocument**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="key1" value="3" />
            <add key="key2" value="1" />
        </appSettings>
    </configuration>

    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

    XmlNode keyNode1 = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings/add[@key='key1']");
    keyNode1.ParentNode.RemoveChild(keyNode1);

    xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```